# 'TfidfVectorizer' object has no attribute 'vocabulary_'

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, tf.keras

`print(tfidf.vocabulary_)`

```
saya memiliki code berikut yang salah
```

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import string
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix, classification_report
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.utils import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, LSTM, Dropout
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
```

```
#mengambil data
x = data['tweet_join'].values
y = data['Label']
```

```
#tokenisasi data
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=1000, oov_token='<OOV>')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data['tweet_join'])
x = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data['tweet_join'])
x = pad_sequences(x, maxlen=1000)
```

```
y = pd.get_dummies(data['Label']).values
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)
```

```
print(f'Jumlah Data Latih : ', len(x_train))
print(f'Jumlah Data Uji : ', len(x_test))
```

```
#Membuat model RNN
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(2000, 128, input_length=x_train.shape[1]))
model.add(LSTM(60, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```
model.summary()
```

```
#kompilasi dan pelatihan model
model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

### `Epoch 1/10
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:1176: SyntaxWarning: In loss categorical_crossentropy, expected y_pred.shape to be (batch_size, num_classes) with num_classes > 1. Received: y_pred.shape=(None, 1). Consider using 'binary_crossentropy' if you only have 2 classes.
return dispatch_target(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 2>()
1 #kompilasi dan pelatihan model
----> 2 model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), epochs=10, batch_size=32)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
13                 try:
14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
16                 except:
17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_step
    loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1109, in compute_loss
    return self.compiled_loss(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
    loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 142, in __call__
    losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 268, in call  **
    return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1984, in categorical_crossentropy
    return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5559, in categorical_crossentropy
    target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

ValueError: Shapes (None, 2) and (None, 1) are incompatible`
```